# BigDecimal for calculation

Tags: java

How can I update a BigDecimal field. Like

```
static BigDecimal balance;

void updateBalance(BigDecimal increment){
balance= new BigDecimal ("0.00");
balance.add(increment);
}

BigDecimal getBalance(){
return balance;
}
```

Comment: `balance = balance.add(increment);`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `String`, the `BigDecimal` class is *immutable*. Every operation (plus, multiply etc.) returns a new instance, rather than updating the instance you have.

In your case, you would need to write something like this:

```
private BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

public void addToBalance(BigDecimal increment) {
    balance = balance.add(increment);
}

public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
```